# A QWidget in a QLayout is shifted and cut when window is maximized

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

There is a simple GUI: main window with a default central widget. A layout is added to it and then a widget of interest is placed to the layout.

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

FormClass, QtBaseClass = loadUiType('main_window.ui')


class MainWindow(FormClass, QtBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.fig = Figure(facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='red', linewidth=0.1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        hbox_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        hbox_layout.addWidget(self.canvas, stretch=2)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main_window.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>768</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1024</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

When the main window is not maximized, everything seems good:

[image]

The whole widget is visible (notice a red border, it was added to monitor the edges of the widget).

But if we maximize the main window, this is what happens:

[image]

Looks like the widget is shifted upwards, the top border of the widget disappears, while at the bottom a black line appears under the edge.

I've tested it with HBox/VBox/Grid layouts, the result is always the same. This happens if there is only one widget in a column. If we add one more widget to the column, both widgets will be fully visible.

Why does it happen and how to fix this behavior? Are we not supposed to have a single widget in a column inside a layout?

OS: Windows 10
Qt: 5.6.2
PyQt: 5.6.0

Comment: This is possibly a bug, but you need a complete reproduction case, in C++, to submit a bug report. You also need one for this to be a valid question (it could be in PyQt here of course).

Comment: Agree, it's probably strange to answer a question here without the code, but it's so basic and helloworldish, that I can hardly imagine how the code itself can affect that bahavior. Anyway, I have updated the question. Can anyone reproduce that?

Comment: @wombatonfire I think it is a bug, report it, but on the other hand you are using an old version of Qt and PyQt, the current version of both libraries is 5.11, and the latest LTS version is 5.9

Comment: I am tied to Anaconda distribution currently. Qt 5.6 is the latest supported version there, and it also seems to be an active LTS release. Thank you all for your comments, I've reported a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked it by creating a new Qt Widgets Application and the issue is not present. To paint the widget I use Qt Style Sheets as follow:

```
QWidget {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

When the application runs it shows well even maximized (see bellow). Re-evaluate the method you use to paint the widget. You can change Style Sheets by using the Style Sheet property in the designer.
See also: [Qt Style Sheets Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).

[image: Normal State]
[image: Maximized State]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure this is a relevant comparison. You are on on Linux, I am on Windows. Platform differences should play a significant role. Anyway, what exact Qt version are you using? My behavior might be version specific.

Comment: @wombatonfire I've tested a minimal example in Windows with the stylesheet mentioned in this answer and it works correctly. Qt 5.10.0, VS 2017, 32 bits.

Comment: I tested it on Windows 10 using Qt 5.11.0. Looks as fine as in Linux. You should upgrade to a latest Qt version. If both are Qt5, they are compatible no matter what, and you should be able to recompile your app without make changes to the source code.